# How to post picking list for a group of sales orders?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I have a custom table with a list of sales orders I want to post picking lists for.

How can I pass them all at once to the SalesFormLetter object to pick them in a group?

I see SalesFormLetter_PickingList\newJournalList is being called, and I was wondering if there was a way I could just pass a simple RecordSortedList in of the sales orders I wanted to pick.  That list is of the wrong table though...so that wouldn't work.  It looks like I can somehow pass a query but I'm not exactly sure how to do that.  Here is the basic code I'm using to post the picking lists:

```
salesFormLetter = SalesFormLetter::construct(DocumentStatus::PickingList);
salesFormLetter.update(SalesTable::find(_salesId), today(), SalesUpdate::All, AccountOrder::None, NoYes::No, NoYes::Yes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This involves setting up a query to select your sales orders then calling the `chooseLines` to  select the orders.

Answer (score 1):

by: Jubal1234Posted on 2010-07-27 at 04:13:28ID: 33296972

Found the solution:

```
SalesFormLetter salesFormLetter;
QueryRun queryRun;
Query query;
str strSalesTable = "V683904, V683905, V683906";
;
salesFormLetter = SalesFormLetter::construct(DocumentStatus::PackingSlip);
query = new Query(QueryStr(SalesUpdate));
query.dataSourceTable(tablenum(SalesTable)).addRange(fieldnum(SalesTable, SalesId)).value(strSalesTable);
queryRun = new QueryRun(query);

salesFormLetter.chooseLinesQuery(queryRun);
salesFormLetter.transDate(systemdateget());
salesFormLetter.specQty(SalesUpdate::All);
salesFormLetter.printFormLetter(false);

salesFormLetter.createParmUpdate();
salesFormLetter.chooseLines(null,true);
salesFormLetter.reArrangeNow(true);
salesFormLetter.run();
```

Case closed